# Dropbox: how do I get the ACL for a file?

Tags: dropbox-api

Given a file, how can I find who the file is visible to (shared with)?

This doesn't appear to be in metadata, and the /shares path generates a link.

So, how can we tell who has access?

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API currently does not offer a way to find the shared status of files like this.